# why return type deduction can not support SFINAE with std::is_invocable_v

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, sfinae, return-type-deduction

there is some functors with **return type deduction**, including *lambda expressions*.

```cpp
constexpr auto a = [](auto&& x){ return x + 1; };
struct X{
    template<typename T>
    auto operator()(T&& x){
        return x + 1;
    }
};
```

and then, I have 2 functions to check if the arguments can be applied to these functors, by `std::is_invocable_v` and **SFINAE**.

```cpp
template<typename F, typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<F, T>, int> = 0>
void foo(T a){
    std::cout << "yes" << std::endl;
}
template<typename F, typename T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_invocable_v<F, T>, int> = 0>
void foo(T a){
    std::cout << "no" << std::endl;
}
```

finally, I use `foo<X>(0)` or `foo<decltype(a)>(0)`, and it works well and says "yes" because the check is passed. but when I use `foo<X>((void*)0)` or `foo<decltype(a)>((void*)0)`, I receive **compile error** instead of "no".

> *Substitution occurs in*
>
> *1. all **types** used in the **function type** (which includes **return type** and the **types of all parameters**)*
>
> ...

it looks like, these functors will accept arguments of any type, and then throw an error if `x + 1` is ill-formed. but, the return type of `operator()` is deduced by `x + 1`, which means it depends on the argument's type `T`. when the `std::is_invocable_v` is instantiated, `T` is substituted by `void*`, and then the signature of  `operator()` has **an invalid return type**. is this ***substitute failure***?

---

to clarify this question, I define these 2 functors:

```cpp
struct Y{
    template<typename T>
    decltype(auto) operator()(T&& x){
        return x + 1;
    }
};
struct Z{
    template<typename T>
    auto operator()(T&& x)->decltype(x + 1){
        return x + 1;
    }
};
```

> *If the return type is `decltype(auto)`, the return type is as **what would be obtained if the expression used in the return statement were wrapped in `decltype`***.

but why `foo<Z>((void*)0)` says "no" but `foo<Y>((void*)0)` result in an error?

Comment: can't reproduce! Compiles with some warnings, because doing arithmetic's on pointers, but all compiles. Instead of filling long text, you should give us the real code. Maybe I transferred it wrongly from your text description.

Comment: @Klaus that's because gcc allows arithmrtics of `void*`(in fact, by SFINAE, gcc still think `(void*)0+1` is ill-formed), you should forbid it or use clang.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [[dcl.spec.auto]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.spec.auto#11).

Deduced return types are not SFINAE-friendly, in the sense that querying the return type of a templated callable (function template / generic lambda / functor with templated `operator()(...)`) which leverages return type deduction requires instantiation of the particular specialization of the callable, as the definition of the specialization is needed in order to deduce the return type:

> **[dcl.spec.auto]/11** Return type deduction for a function template with a placeholder in
> its declared type occurs when the definition is instantiated even if
> the function body contains a return statement with a
> non-type-dependent operand. [ **Note: Therefore, any use of a
> specialization of the function template will cause an implicit
> instantiation. Any errors that arise from this instantiation are not
> in the immediate context of the function type and can result in the
> program being ill-formed** ([temp.deduct]).  — end note ] [ Example:
>
> ```
> template <class T> auto f(T t) { return t; }    // return type deduced at instantiation time
> typedef decltype(f(1)) fint_t;                  // instantiates f<int> to deduce return type
> template<class T> auto f(T* t) { return *t; }
> void g() { int (*p)(int*) = &f; }               // instantiates both fs to determine return types,
>                                                 // chooses second
> ```
>
> — end example ]

Due to the implementation of `std::is_invocable`, which applies `decltype` on the (unevaluated) expression of invoking of the callable specialization (to find the return type), return type deduction is triggered for the specialization, which requires the specialization to be instantiated, which results in, in this case, as highlighted in the (non-normative) note above, the program being ill-formed.

Comment: I'm not sure it matters whether `decltype` is applied to the invoke expression - I think the compiler will always instantiate the definition just because of the (unevaluated) call. I am not sure about this, so I asked https://stackoverflow.com/q/64915753/481267

Comment: @Brian Interesting question. I always thought it return type deduction for a callable in an unevaluated expression only triggered if that expression was an unevaluated operator for `decltype`.