# If a function template has deduced return type, is there a way to call it without instantiating the definition?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

Consider some function template such as:

```
template <class T>
const auto& foo() { static T t; return t; }
```

The definition would not be valid if `T` were to be `void`. Nonetheless, we are allowed to instantiate the *declaration* alone without triggering an error:

```
extern template const auto& foo<void>();  // explicit instantiation declaration
```

Now let's consider situations where `foo` is called, rather than being explicitly instantiated. Obviously, if `foo` is ever called in an evaluated context, the definition of the specialization will be instantiated. What about in an unevaluated context? We know that if a function template with a non-deduced return type is called in an unevaluated context, the definition of the specialization is not instantiated. The obvious example of this is `std::declval<T>`. It's not clear whether the same is possible for a function that has a deduced return type.

For example, I considered this:

```
static_assert(sizeof( (void)foo<void>(), char{} ) == 1);
```

However, even in this situation, where the compiler definitely has enough information to evaluate the `sizeof` expression without knowing the return type, a compilation error still occurs ([godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/nhK6c8)).

- What provision of the Standard requires the instantiation of the definition of `foo<void>` in this situation?
- Is there any way that `foo<void>` can be called inside an unevaluated expression that would not instantiate its definition?

Comment: _What provision of the Standard requires the instantiation of the definition of foo<void> in this situation?_ The standard only requires it when taking address of a function https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.funcaddr#2 :/

Comment: I asked [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64917707/4573247), where explicit instantiation declarations of specializations of non-template member functions of class templates seemingly leads to the instantiations of the associated class template specializations (as per GCC/Clang). That the return types of the member function is deduced may not be relevant in my question, but I use it mainly to get the backing of [dcl.spec.auto]/14 that the explicit instantiation declarations shall not cause instantiations.

Comment: _We know that if a function template with a non-deduced return type is called in an unevaluated context, the definition of the specialization is not instantiated_ I've thought it is CWG1378.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What provision of the Standard requires the instantiation of the definition of `foo<void>` in this situation?

Albeit non-normative, the note in [[dcl.spec.auto]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.spec.auto#11) does mention that *any* use of a specialization (of a function template with a placeholder in its declared return type) will cause an implicit instantiation [extract, **emphasis** mine]:

> [...] [ *Note:* Therefore, **any use of a specialization** of the function template will cause an implicit instantiation.

and, moreover, [[dcl.spec.auto]/14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.spec.auto#14) covers the particular case of allowing an explicit instantiation declaration without triggering an instantiation, whilst arguably also hinting that the instantiation mechanisms triggered for determining the return type for a function template are somewhat separated from the "regular" instantiation mechanisms [**emphasis** mine]:

> An explicit instantiation declaration does not cause the instantiation of an entity declared using a placeholder type, **but it also does not prevent that entity from being instantiated as needed to determine its type**. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> template <typename T> auto f(T t) { return t; }
> extern template auto f(int);    // does not instantiate f<int>
> int (*p)(int) = f;              // instantiates f<int> to determine its return type, but an explicit
>                                 // instantiation definition is still required somewhere in the program
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

where the comment (non-normative) to the example points out that such a special-case triggered implicit instantiation is only used for return type deduction, and does not waive the need for an explicit instantiation definition elsewhere.

---

> Is there any way that `foo<void>` can be called inside an unevaluated expression that would not instantiate its definition?

Given the discussion above, I would say: no. Calling even within an unevaluated expression would fall under the (non-normative) "any use of".