# Does an explicit instantiation declaration of a member function of a class template cause instantiation of the class template?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, instantiation, friend

[[dcl.spec.auto]/14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.spec.auto#14) states [**emphasis** mine]:

> **An explicit instantiation declaration does not cause the instantiation of an entity declared using a placeholder type**, but it also does not prevent that entity from being instantiated as needed to determine its type. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> template <typename T> auto f(T t) { return t; }
> extern template auto f(int);    // does not instantiate f<int>
> int (*p)(int) = f;              // instantiates f<int> to determine its return type, but an explicit
>                                 // instantiation definition is still required somewhere in the program
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

and [[temp.explicit]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.explicit#11) states [**emphasis** mine]:

> **An entity** that is the subject of an **explicit instantiation declaration** and that is **also used in a way that would otherwise cause an implicit instantiation** in the translation unit **shall be the subject of an explicit instantiation definition somewhere in the program;** otherwise the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

Now, consider the following program:

```
template <class T>
struct Foo {
    static const auto& foo() { static T t; return t; }
};

// explicit instantiation declarations
extern template const auto& Foo<void>::foo();
extern template const auto& Foo<int>::foo();

int main() {}
```

This is well-formed; [[temp.explicit]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.explicit#11) does not apply as neither member function of class template specialization entities `Foo<void>::foo()` nor `Foo<int>::foo()` are used in a way that would otherwise cause an implicit instantiation, as per [[dcl.spec.auto]/14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.spec.auto#14)<sup>(1)</sup>.

Now, consider if we defined a friend function at its friend declaration in the class template `Foo`:

```
template <class T>
struct Foo {
    static const auto& foo() { static T t; return t; }
    friend void bar() { }
};
void bar();
```

If any more than one specialization of `Foo` is instantiated in the same translation unit, [[basic.def.odr]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.def.odr#1) will be violated:

> No translation unit shall contain more than one definition of any variable, function, class type, enumeration type, or template.

as the friend `bar()` would be re-defined<sup>(2)</sup> for each specialization that is instantiated.

According to the argument above, the explicit instantiation declarations of the two  member function (of class template) specializations should not lead to any instantiation of the associated class template (as per [[dcl.spec.auto]/14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.spec.auto#14)), meaning the following program should also arguably be well-formed:

```
template <class T>
struct Foo {
    static const auto& foo() { static T t; return t; }
    friend void bar() { }
};
void bar();

extern template const auto& Foo<void>::foo();
extern template const auto& Foo<int>::foo();

int main() {}
```

However, both Clang (10.0.0) and GCC (10.1.0) rejects the program (C++14, C++17, C++2a) with a "redefinition of `void bar()`” error:

> **Clang**
>
> error: redefinition of `bar`
>
> note: in instantiation of template class `Foo<int>` requested here:
> `extern template const auto& Foo<int>::foo();`
>
> **GCC**
>
> In instantiation of `struct Foo<int>`:
>
> error: redefinition of `void bar()`

But I never requested (or, afaict, used these specializations in a way such that) the `Foo<int>` or `Foo<void>` specializations (are) to be instantiated.

Thus to the question:

- Is the program (with the friend) above well-formed, or are the compilers correct to instantiate the class template specializations and subsequently reject the program?

---

<sub>(1) Note the the same question (and compiler behaviour) applies even if `foo()` is not declared using a placeholder type, but then we would not be able to fall back on the explicitness of [[dcl.spec.auto]/14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.spec.auto#14), but we may not need to.</sub>

<sub>(2) As friends defined at their friend declaration are inline, we may actually instantiate different specializations in different translation units and still respect ODR, but this is not relevant in this discussion.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument that the class template must be instantiated is that declaration **matching** may need to know things about the class that plainly require instantiation.  Consider the simplified example

```
template<class T>
struct A {void f(T) {}};

extern template void A<int>::f(int);
```

To know whether the member function exists, we must instantiate the declaration in the class template, and we can’t do that in general without instantiating the whole class: the parameter type could depend on any **other** declarations in the class template, and we might need to consider multiple overloads or even do template argument deduction to decide which `f` is meant.  One can argue that instantiation should happen only if one of these situations actually pertains, which strays into [CWG2](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#2) territory (where instantiation is obviously impossible), but the idea is that instantiation is necessary in principle to **decide** about such questions because we simply don’t *try* examining the template itself first.

Comment: Thanks, it sounds _reasonable_, that **i)** explicit instantiation declarations naturally needs to be matched (declaration matching), and that **ii)** whilst a template function with deduced return type can avoid being instantiated solely for declaration matching (and is even required to do so, by [dcl.spec.auto]/14), a non-template member function of a class template cannot (as per your example). However, the latter of **ii)** is arguably under-specified; do you happen to have a normative reference for this declaration matching argument, is this essentially (under-specified as per) CWG 2?

Comment: @dfrib: You’re not actually instantiating the member function, by which we mean instantiating its **definition** — just its declaration (which involves instantiating the definition of the class).  The standard is very vague about declaration-only instantiation, as happens during overload resolution and for templates that are “instantiated” before being defined.  The only relevant text for your case is in [temp.inst]/2, where dependence on the list of members of a specialization is described as one of the reasons for instantiation.

Comment: I see, thanks. I guess _"[...] [when the completeness of the class type affects the semantics of the program.](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#2.sentence-1)"_ may be used as an umbrella to capture a lot. The rules for declaration-only instantiations seems particularly vague when considering friends defined at their friend declarations within a class template. This is kind of an anti-pattern and not really an issue prior to C++20, but as of [US115](https://github.com/cplusplus/nbballot/issues/114) from [P2103R0](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2020/p2103r0.html) this could ...

Comment: ... possibly become an issue. Particularly if devs start constraining hidden friends whose function parameter's type and result type are not dependent on any template parameters (for which we see a large compiler variance atm; contrived possibly ill-formed demos [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tF6uXnzqFTUx0Wp5) and [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/n8NCSdrXeTVPAhhK)). Interestingly, this was explicitly banned in [temp.friend]/10 in [N3819](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3819.pdf), but this restriction has since been waived.